# x264 Building error - Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am using  this repository to build ffmpeg static library which includes x264,libpng and others, please 
visit this link https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android

i am using windows 7 as host and ubuntu 15.10 (_64)  as guest os using VMware Workstation 12 
and

Android-ndk-r11b-linux-x86_64

> i do have Prebuilt  libraries , but now i want it without PIE support

i am getting this error in config.log in x264 folder while building
through

> ./android_build.sh

here is the log :

```
x264 configure script
Command line options: "--cross-prefix=/mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux 
/mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc 

checking whether /mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc 

--sysroot=/mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot works... no

 Failed commandline was:

--sysroot=/mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot    --sysroot=/mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot -lm -o conftest

/mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: fatal error:

conftest: Input/output error

Failed program was: 

int main (void) {  return 0; }

DIED: No working C compiler found.
```

ushare is my shared folder between windows and ubuntu

I have spend almost a week ,trying to solve every  error i get.

these errors are like never ending , 1 solution give 10 more errors

i have researched a **LOT** for this library

thanks a lot in advance.

> Also i thought that x264 library might have poroblem ,so i tried to disable it
>   but next library "libpng" also had Same log Error

i think problem is in Input/output error (obviously)

this line in log kind of confuses me (those /../../)

> /mnt/hgfs/uShare/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: fatal error:

its like two folder overlaping address...

thanks a lot in advance.

 please don't go harsh on me ,its my first time,all thanks to this thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved my problem. the problem was in NDK ,i extracted it in windows and was using it on ubuntu. Later i used ubuntu to extract ,and found the built to be working.

hope this help to new future users!